# How to decode the output of an eth_call that returns a Tuple[]

Tags: abi, bytecode, bytes, rlp, eth-call

I am developing a low-level library that interacts with RPC nodes directly. There is a requirement to call the AaveV2 `getAllReserveTokens` function, and I want to decode the output data.

The particular function that I am calling is this: https://etherscan.io/address/0x057835Ad21a177dbdd3090bB1CAE03EaCF78Fc6d#readContract#F3

When I do an eth_call, the output is a long output, I have pasted it here: https://paste.ee/p/TJ5cr

As you can see on etherscan, the output type is a `tuple[]`, and the abi specifies that the tuple contains a `string` and `address`.

I understood that the first 32 bytes is the offset, from where the dynamic array starts, so `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020` = 32.

The second 32 bytes is the length of the array, and hence, the array is of length `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000025` = 37.

This all tracks with the output of the etherscan function call.

However, I cannot figure out how to decode the rest of the data. Please can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After re-reading https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/abi-spec.html#use-of-dynamic-types with a fresher brain, I understood that the way the bytes are divided is as follows:

first 32 bytes: offset for the list of tuples

next 32 bytes: length of the list (37)

next 37*32 bytes: each defining the start position for the respective tuples

each tuple (starting at the start position from above) has the offset for the start of the string (which always corresponds to the position after the address), and then the address, followed by the length of the string and then the string.

This has really helped me understand how complex data types are encoded in RLP.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source code of the contract, the return type of the function `getAllReserveTokens` is `TokenData[] memory` which is an array of a custom struct defined in the storage of the contract. The `bytes` you are receiving as a response from the contract is the RLP encoded bytes of the data. All data is stored in this form on the EVM.

Not sure what framework you are working in, but the same methodology is easily reproducible in most common languages. Simply define a local instance of the struct, and decode the bytes received from the call with the `TokenData[]` type as the second parameter. Here's a little foundry snippet.

```js
    contract AaveTest is DSTest {
        CheatCodes cheatCodes;
    
        struct TokenData {
            string symbol;
            address tokenAddress;
        }
    
        address AAVE_PROTOCOL_DATA_PROVIDER =
            0x057835Ad21a177dbdd3090bB1CAE03EaCF78Fc6d;
    
        function setUp() public {
            cheatCodes = CheatCodes(HEVM_ADDRESS);
        }
    
        function testEncodeAaveReturn() public {
            (bool success, bytes memory data) = AAVE_PROTOCOL_DATA_PROVIDER.call(
                abi.encodeWithSignature("getAllReservesTokens()")
            );
            assertTrue(success);
            TokenData[] memory tokens = abi.decode(data, (TokenData[]));
    
            for (uint256 i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                console.log(tokens[i].symbol);
            }
    
            bytes memory encoded = abi.encode(tokens);
    
            assertEq(string(encoded), string(data));
        }
    }
```

*In Typescript for example you could use `ethersjs`, `ethers-rs` (rust) `go-ethereum` (go) ..etc:*

```js
    const iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(AAVE_DATA_PROVIDER_ABI)
    interface TokenData = { symbol:string, tokenAddress:string; }
    
    //Convert the byte array to a string if its not already
    function decode(data:string) public {
        const tokenData:TokenData = iface.decodeFunctionResult("getAllReservesTokens()", data);
    
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I appreciate it.
I am trying to develop my own library in java so I'm trying to not use libraries like `web3j`. Is it possible, knowing that the return type is a list of structs containing a string and an address, to parse the output chunk by chunk?